# Get response of google indexing api in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, api, curl, indexing

I am trying to setup google indexing api in codeigniter, I have done all steps on google cloud and search console part.

It works, but returning success message on all options event when url is not submited, that is why I want to get exact response from google instead of a created success message.

How can I display exact response from google `return $stringBody;`? or check for the correct response ?

Here is my controller :

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\LanguageModel;
use App\Models\IndexingModel;

class IndexingController extends BaseController
{
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        $this->indexingModel = new IndexingModel();
    }
    
    public function GoogleUrl()
    {
        checkPermission('indexing_api');
        $data['title'] = trans("indexing_api");
        $data["selectedLangId"] = inputGet('lang');

        if (empty($data["selectedLangId"])) {
            $data["selectedLangId"] = $this->activeLang->id;
        }

        echo view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
        echo view('admin/indexing_api', $data);
        echo view('admin/includes/_footer');
    }

    /**
     * indexing Tools Post
     */
    public function indexingToolsPost()
    {
      checkPermission('indexing_api');
      $slug = inputPost('slug');
      $urltype = inputPost('urltype');
      $val = \Config\Services::validation();
      $val->setRule('slug', trans("slug"), 'required|max_length[500]');
      if (!$this->validate(getValRules($val))) {
          $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', $val->getErrors());
          return redirect()->to(adminUrl('indexing_api?slug=' . cleanStr($slug)))->withInput();
      } else {
        $this->indexingModel->AddUrlToGoogle($slug, $urltype);
        $this->session->setFlashdata('success', trans("msg_added"));
        resetCacheDataOnChange();
        return redirect()->to(adminUrl('indexing_api?slug=' . cleanStr($slug)));
      }
      $this->session->setFlashdata('error', trans("msg_error"));
      return redirect()->to(adminUrl('indexing_api?slug=' . cleanStr($slug)))->withInput();
    }
}
```

And This is my model :

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use Google_Client;

class IndexingModel extends BaseModel {
  
  public function AddUrlToGoogle($google_url, $Urltype){
      
    require_once APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    
    $client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/google-api-php-client/xxxxxxxxx.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

    $httpClient = $client->authorize();
    $endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

    $array = ['url' => $google_url, 'type' => $Urltype];
    $content = json_encode($array);

    $response = $httpClient->post($endpoint,['body' => $content]);
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $stringBody = (string)$body;
        
    return $stringBody;
  }
  
  public function AddUrlToBing($google_url, $Urltype){
      
      
  }
  
  public function AddUrlToYandex($google_url, $Urltype){
      
      
  }
}
```

This is a success response when I try it out of codeigniter and `print_r($stringBody);`

```
{ "urlNotificationMetadata": { "url": "https://example.com/some-text", "latestUpdate": { "url": "https://example.com/some-text", "type": "URL_UPDATED", "notifyTime": "2023-01-29T01:51:13.140372319Z" } } }
```

And this is an error response :

```
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Unknown notification type. 'type' attribute is required.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

But In codeigniter I get a text message "url submited" even if url not submited.

Comment: Can you show an example response?

Comment: If you are asking especially for the "empty url" case, you could check this condition beforehand yourself. Is that an option?

Comment: @I added success response to bottom of the question you can check. I means, I get success message even if url is not submited. yes that is an option I tried several combination in model but couldnt get the corect response. I need to return correct response like : url not submited or url submited. all options are acceptale :)

Comment: Does it make a  difference, if you leave the `url` value empty, or leaving the url parameter at all?

Comment: If the api does accept something you consider wrong, then you might apply validation on your side.

Comment: Why isn't `required|max_length[500]` validation working at all? It should fail in the controller even before `AddUrlToGoogle()` when the `url`(`$slug`) is empty, right?

Comment: Considering the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/core-errors?hl=en#BAD_REQUEST), you should get a `400 Bad Request` - `Missing attribute. 'url' attribute is required.`

Comment: Your "success response" contains `"url": "https://example.com/some-text"`. Are you sure you are sending an empty URL?

Comment: You are correct. so I need to change this : `$this->session->setFlashdata('success', trans("msg_added"));` to get real response, but how ? yes I do everything correctly except this :`$this->session->setFlashdata('success', trans("msg_added"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are not handling the actual response of `IndexingModel->AddUrlToGoogle()`. It seems your code has a validation before, so it claims, if no validation error occurs, its always a success.

So the first question to ask is, why your validation is not working here - or is it?

Secondly you could handle the actual response in any case:

**IndexingController**

```
class IndexingController extends BaseController

    public function indexingToolsPost()
    {
      if (!$this->validate(getValRules($val))) {
          // validation error
          $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', $val->getErrors());
          return redirect()->to(adminUrl('indexing_api?slug=' . cleanStr($slug)))->withInput();
      } else {
        // no validation error
        $apiResponseBody = $this->indexingModel->AddUrlToGoogle($slug, $urltype);
        if(array_key_exists('error', $apiResponseBody)) {
            // its an error!
            // either set the actual messsage
            $this->session->setFlashdata('error', $apiResponseBody['error']['message']);
            // OR translate it
            $this->session->setFlashdata('error', trans($apiResponseBody['error']['message']));
        } else {
           // Its a success!
           $this->session->setFlashdata('success', trans("msg_added"));
        }
        // ...
      }
      return redirect()->to(adminUrl('indexing_api?slug=' . cleanStr($slug)))->withInput();
    }
```

And in the model, return the response as an array:

**IndexingModel**

```
  public function AddUrlToGoogle($google_url, $Urltype) {
    // ...

    $response = $httpClient->post($endpoint,['body' => $content]);
    return json_decode($response->getBody() ?? '', true);   // return an array
  }
```

Comment: I think I didnt explain it well! gogle returns correct response. its me and my codes returning same response on both options. I need to do if statment something like this 
    `$stringBody = (string)$body; if ($stringBody){ return $stringBody; } else { return false; }` but dont know how to get valid or invalid response conditions from google to do if statament.

Comment: If you send something to the api and get a specific response, you cannot change that response at all by just sending the same request. Do you understand what I mean? You may have not influence on the APIs requirements. If it accepts an empty value for a param that you consider "is required" you must check it yourself. Doing it via such a `if`-statement is indded an option.

Comment: @DLK I updated my answer. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Getting error `array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array`

Comment: I made a mistake in the response type of the models function. Sorry its late here :p can you try again, checking my udpated answer?

Comment: Another way could be to decide between success and error by the response **code**.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy! you put good affort on it. got it working with a litle changes. Late for me too. good night to both of us